# Android WebView stopped unexpectly after loading an url

Tags: android, android-webview

i have a big problem and i did not find a solution for my problem.

I try to load an url and i use this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

**My Code:**

```
public class HomeView extends Activity
{

    WebView mWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**my home.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Now my problem. If i start the program everything works fine. The page is loading and i see it on the screen. but then after everything is loaded, i get the following message (the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again.) and my programm is terminated.

Hope somebody can help me.

Cheers, 
Roland

**My Log:**

```
09-16 12:59:14.154: WARN/cache(1204): Unable to create webviewCache directory

09-16 12:59:18.432: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1204): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1931 objects / 221256 bytes in 195ms

09-16 12:59:18.522: WARN/dalvikvm(1204): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewWorkerThread

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204): java.lang.NullPointerException

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getCacheTotalSize(WebViewDatabase.java:734)

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.webkit.CacheManager.trimCacheIfNeeded(CacheManager.java:548)

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:190)

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

09-16 12:59:18.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

09-16 12:59:18.712: WARN/ActivityManager(65):   Force finishing activity de.test.webview/.HomeView

09-16 12:59:19.283: WARN/InputManagerService(65): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43ecba70 (uid=10035 pid=1204)

09-16 12:59:21.976: DEBUG/dalvikvm(263): GC_EXPLICIT freed 65 objects / 2968 bytes in 4365ms

09-16 13:00:39.013: DEBUG/SntpClient(65): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

09-16 13:04:19.383: INFO/Process(1204): Sending signal. PID: 1204 SIG: 9

09-16 13:04:19.474: WARN/InputManagerService(65): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43e92c50

09-16 13:04:19.742: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Process de.test.webview (pid 1204) has died.
```

Comment: Strange. can you post your Logcat Exception Message.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a small mistake in my code.

**`@Override`**

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

With @Override everything works fine.

Comment: these kind of problems sucks sometimes